# Insect identification Colorado

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We found this bug in our house today. So far have not been able to identify it after past hour online. Its pincers look way larger than most normal beetles I can find. Can someone help us finger out more about this critter? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the closest I can find is a stag beetle? Although we are in the city and not heavily forested

Comment: It looks a lot like [dorcus curvidens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorcus_curvidens), but according to the wikipedia page, it's found in Japan. But I would lean heavily towards a dorcus species.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a cottonwood stage beetle. Lucanidae, *Lucanus mazama* https://bugguide.net/node/view/666700/bgimage